# How to read console input when using console.readline to keep process alive as well?

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application

I'm learning/experimenting with SpotifyAPI.Net DotNetCore console application and have trouble reading user input from the console. I think the console.readline() in the main thread (used for keeping the console app alive) takes precedence over the one i have in one of my methods.
How do i get console input when having it keep the main thread alive at the same time?

I've been searching about this for days but all I can find is questions on how to keep console apps alive.

I'm beginning to think I'm better off trying to use some simple UI?

in my main method:

```
AuthorizationCodeAuth auth =
                new AuthorizationCodeAuth(_clientId, _secretId, "http://localhost:4002", "http://localhost:4002",
                    Scope.PlaylistReadPrivate | Scope.PlaylistReadCollaborative);
            auth.AuthReceived += AuthOnAuthReceived;
            auth.Start();
            auth.OpenBrowser();
            Console.ReadLine();
            auth.Stop(0);
```

and then AuthOnAuthReceived is:

```
        {
            AuthorizationCodeAuth auth = (AuthorizationCodeAuth) sender;
            auth.Stop();



            Token token = await auth.ExchangeCode(payload.Code);
            SpotifyWebAPI api = new SpotifyWebAPI
            {
                AccessToken = token.AccessToken,
                TokenType = token.TokenType
            };
            PrintUsefulData(api);
        }
```

PrintusefulData then does some things is where I want to grab some user console input with basic shit like:
`var input = Console.ReadLine();`

But when debugging it never gets beyond this line of code because the program terminates because the readline in the main thread gets input and then it terminates.

I would expect there to be some way to keep a console program alive while also getting some input from the user in the console. But all my variations just end up terminating due to the userinput and never reaching the code I want to use for reading and processing the input.

I'm guessing I'm being a total newbie and missing something very obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a look at [synchronization primitives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/overview-of-synchronization-primitives), e.g. the [ManualResetEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualresetevent). This will allow you to use `WaitOne` instead `ReadLine` to wait for the callback to be executed in your `main` method. `WaitOne` will block until `Set` is called, which you can do in `AuthOnAuthReceive`.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into this :)

Comment: This lead to a working solution indeed. It looked a bit complex and intimidating at first but doing WaitOne() after starting the browser and then having manualResetEvent.Set(); at the very end  of my PrintUsefulData() method worked exactly as needed. Thanks again for the help :)